# WooCommerce - Calculate Tax Before Applying Coupons

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm working on a WooCommerce project, and I need to calculate taxes based on the original price of products before applying any coupons (discounts). Currently, the default behavior is that taxes are calculated after coupons are applied, resulting in incorrect tax calculations.

For example, consider the following scenario:

Product 1: $141.51
Product 2: $35.85
Coupon: $120

Currently, the cart calculates taxes as follows:

Subtotal of items: $141.51
Applying coupon: -$113.21
Shipping: $35.85
Tax: $3.85
Final cart total: $68

However, what I want is:

Subtotal of items: $141.51
Shipping: $35.85
Tax: $10.64
Applying coupon: -$120
Final cart total: $68

This is because a coupon is a valid form of payment, and in the country where I reside, it is not possible to impose taxes on coupons. Additionally, this project is integrated with accounting software, so it's crucial that the prices and taxes are accurate.

I've implemented the following code to try and calculate taxes correctly:

```
function custom_calculate_tax( $cart_object ) {
    // Calculate total discount based on coupons
    $total_discount = 0;

    foreach ( $cart_object->get_applied_coupons() as $coupon_code ) {
        $coupon = new WC_Coupon( $coupon_code );
        if ( $coupon->is_type( 'fixed_cart' ) ) {
            $total_discount += $coupon->get_amount();
        }
    }

    // Calculate tax rate for the full price before discounts
    $full_price = $cart_object->subtotal + $cart_object->shipping_total - $total_discount;
    $tax_rates = WC_Tax::get_rates( $cart_object->tax_class );

    // Add log recording to check what's happening
    error_log( 'Full Price: ' . $full_price );
    error_log( 'Total Discount: ' . $total_discount );
    error_log( 'Tax Rates: ' . print_r( $tax_rates, true ) );

    // Calculate taxes
    $taxes = WC_Tax::calc_tax( $full_price, $tax_rates, false );

    // Add taxes to the cart
    $cart_object->taxes = $taxes;

    // Apply the discount (coupons)
    $cart_object->cart_contents_total -= $total_discount;
    $cart_object->cart_contents_tax += array_sum( $taxes );

    // Recalculate the total price
    $cart_object->calculate_totals();

    return $cart_object;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'custom_calculate_tax', 9999);
```